# Count number of appearance

Tags: c#, string, serial-port

Currently I have a string declare as RxString. Rxstring represent string of data like for example:

```
T  112   22.0
```

Now I need to extract out the middle value of the data to do a comparison. Therefore i do a split. Code as below:

```
string[] number = RxString.Split(' '); 
string unit = number[1];
```

So now the middle value is declare as string unit.

Data is being received from a serial port, for example :

```
T  11   22.2
T  42   22.0
T  42   22.0
T  42   23.2
T  22   20.8
```

Based on the number of appearance of the middle value, I need to execute some action. For instance, if 42 happens to appear 4times (one after another) down the row, I need execute an action, else the recording of data will take place as usual. How should I handle the counting?

```
while (serialPort1.IsOpen)
{       
string[] number = RxString.Split(' '); 
string unit = number[1];  

(Code for checking repeat)

if (unit repeats 4times)
{execute an action then record in db then reset counter}
else
{record in db then reset counter} 
}
```

Make sense?

Comment: Are you going to be executing the functions _while_ (as long as) you are receiving data or _for_ a specific, preloaded set of data?

Comment: @BenKnoble My friend suggested to store the unit to array in while loop then use for loop to compare. But I am just lost..

Comment: Why would you need a for loop to do comparison? I would do it this way: while loop for incoming data. Maintain a counter variable for the number of times youve seen 42. Do your storage and then check as outlined in your question, remembering in the branch for executing the action to reset you counter variable.

Comment: @BenKnoble But how should I even start with the while loop coding?

Comment: Google while loops in c#? How are you getting your data? From a method or a stream or?

Comment: @BenKnoble Yes, by a stream. Open a com port and the data will be received and reflect through a textbox

Comment: Monacraft has a good answer for you, although like i said id do something like `while (dataStream has more data)...`

Comment: And then the ... Could be `get middle, check for repeats, increment counter, if enough repeats perform action and reset counter. If no repeats, reset counter. Record in db`

Comment: @BenKnoble Yup.. i guess having a while loop is better..

Comment: Its all pseudocode obviously but it seems to make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have an array, for all the middle values:

```
string[] values = {11, 42, 42, 42, 22};
int count = 1;
for(int i = 1; i < values.Count; i++) {
    if(values[i-1] == values[i])
        count++;
    else
        count = 1;
    if(count == 4 && values[i] == "42")
       Execute();  // Change this
    RecordInDb();  // Change this
}
```

Comment: I dont think I can store the values like this.. the data is not fixed. I'm getting it by streaming..